# Ruby / ROR assignment using or (Default values for checkbox)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to assign a default value to a check box in ROR. The following is the heirachy:

1. Check if value is in the params (url querystring)
2. Check if it's in the session variable
3. If neither, default to all possible values and set @rates to all possible values

I have written the following code:

```
@all_rates = Rates.all_rates
rates_all = {} 
@all_rates.each {|rate| rates_all[rate] = "1"} 
p rates_all
@rates = params[:rates] ||= session[:rates] ||= rates_all
puts @rates.length, @rates
```

when i p rates_all, i get the hash back, however when i check @rates.length it is not being assigned i get a 0.

Comment: BTW, i can get it working using if, elsif, els statement. Not sure why the version above is not working.

Comment: actually it's not even working when doing an if, elsif, else statement. @rates is still {}

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if `params[:rates]` is nil? Because if it's an empty hash then it's still an object, just without any values. But the empty hash object would be assigned to `@rates` anyway, resulting that rates is an empty hash object too, with length 0.

Comment: Yep when i print params, i dont see anything which refers to params[:rates]

Comment: And the same goes for session[:rates]?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
@rates = case 
  when params[:rates].present?
    params[:rates]
  when session[:rates].present?
    session[:rates]
  else 
    Rates.all_rates.inject({}) { |hsh, rate| hsh.merge(rate => '1') }
end
```

Sidebar:
Your model name should be the singular `Rate`. The `||=` syntax in your example is invalid. It should be just `||`.